# How can an account be accessed even though two-step authentication?

Tags: mobile, multi-factor, account-security, facebook

Facebook uses two-step authentication or ["login approval"](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/introducing-login-approvals/10150172618258920/), which means that **all unrecognized devices** will have to enter a code received through SMS. Suppose my Samsung device is the only device that has been logged in to my Facebook account. **What must the attacker do** so that:

- I won't receive any SMS (or at least won't see any)
- I don't receive any e-mail about that
- The attacker gains access to my account and can view messages/be active (liking, commenting)

*What is the most realistic and possible scenario?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different possibilities from the top of my head:

- the identifier of a legitimate device has been compromised (by a MITM with a downgrade attack, for example) and used to identify as such device,
- the mobile phone has been compromised as a whole (forwarding and hiding/deleting SMS and emails),
- SS7-based attack on your mobile number in combination with a compromised email account.